# In Typeahead.js, can you tell if you have more results than the limit?

Tags: typeahead.js, bloodhound

By default, Bloodhound limits the results returned to Typeahead.js to 5. This value is adjustable with the 'limit' option in Bloodhound. Is there any indicator to tell that a Bloodhound received more results than its limit?

Example being:

Bloodhound is set up with a remote call.

The remote call returns 20 items.

Bloodhound's limit is 5.

Typeahead displays 5 items.

How can you know that 15 items were not displayed?